# Syslog is filling up the entire disk space with those entries

Tags: syslog, elementary-os

I just installed a fresh copy of ElementaryOS, and shortly after i did i get my / filesystem filled with large syslog and syslog.1 files the log files are filled with this entry

```
io.elementary.w[1638]: g_bytes_get_data: assertion 'bytes != NULL' failed
io.elementary.w[1638]: ((libnm-core/nm-utils.c:559)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
```

Currently i clear the log with  cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog  but i'm wondering how can i fix this error in the log files

Comment: nm is the network-manager. Look for faulty network devices.

Comment: @paladin any thoughts on how to proceed with a solution?